# Resolving dependencies with NestJS

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I have a fairly strong MERN stack/Javascript background and I'm trying out new technos today: NestJS, which is built around TypeScrypt and OOP programmation, as I understand it.

I'm trying to build a simple API with an authentication via JSON Web Token, so I implemented a `Guard` as the docs states. Note that I didn't go the full "NestJS" route with using `Passport` and its strategies. I prefer implementing my own things with as less libraries as possible when discovering new technos, rather than doing a full copy-paste of a tutorial that I won't remember the next day.

I successfully wrote simple routes and wired up the project with Mongoose and MongoDB, but I stumbled on a strange error regarding hierarchy of imports/exports of NestJS modules.

The error is as follows:

```
[Nest] 37422  - 03/25/2022, 4:49:57 PM   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the JwtAuthGuard (?). Please make sure that the argument ConfigService at index [0] is available in the UsersModule context.
```

Now I use `ConfigModule` and specifically `ConfigService` to have access to my environment variables. I will need it in my `JwtAuthGuard` to have access to my private key and various JWT configs to create/verify tokens.

I declared my `JwtAuthGuard` as follows:

```
import { CanActivate, ExecutionContext, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

@Injectable()
export class JwtAuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private config: ConfigService) {}
  canActivate(
    context: ExecutionContext,
  ): boolean | Promise<boolean> | Observable<boolean> {
    const req = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    // extract Authorization header and verify it here

    // return true/false depending on jwt.verify return
    return false;
  }

  createToken() {
    return jwt.sign(
      { issuer: this.config.get('JWT_ISSUER') },
      this.config.get('JWT_PRIVATE_KEY'),
      { algorithm: this.config.get('JWT_ALGORITHM') },
    );
  }
}
```

Of course, I import `ConfigModule` in my `JwtAuthModule`:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { JwtAuthGuard } from './guard';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';

@Module({
  exports: [JwtAuthGuard],
  providers: [JwtAuthGuard],
  imports: [ConfigModule],
})
export class JwtAuthModule {}
```

And my `UsersModule` (initially) looked like so:

```
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { User, UserSchema } from './schemas/users';
import { UsersController } from './controller';
import { UsersProvider } from './service';
import { JwtAuthModule } from '../jwt-auth/module';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';

@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: User.name, schema: UserSchema }]),
    JwtAuthModule,
  ],
  controllers: [UsersController],
  providers: [UsersProvider],
  exports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: User.name, schema: UserSchema }]),
    UsersProvider,
  ],
})
export class UsersModule {}
```

I said *initially* because, after carefully reading the error, I fiddled around with the code and saw that when I either:

- add `ConfigModule` to the list of **imports** in `UsersModule`, right before `JwtAuthModule`
- add `ConfigModule` to the list of **exports** in `JwtAuthModule`

the error goes away and everything seems to work fine.

The question is: Why do I have to make `ConfigModule` available to `UsersModule` when it, in fact, does not really need it in itself?

---

**Edit**: Forgot to add context: I use `@UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)` decorator on one of my `UsersController` routes/handlers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error, I an only make an assumption that your `UsersController` has `@UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)` somewhere in it. By having this, Nest will try to instantiate the `JwtAuthGuard` in the context of the `UsersModule` context, meaning using the dependencies it has available. As your `JwtAuthGuard` uses `ConfigService`, the exports of the `ConfigModule` need to be avaialble, and this can be done either by having the `JwtAuithModule` import and export the `ConfigModule` or by having the `UsersModule` import the `ConfigModule`.

The reason having `exports: [JwtAuthGuard]` isn't enough is kind of strange, as enhancers aren't providers in the sense that they use the same pre-built context to be built every time. They don't technically belong to a module (at least most of the time, there are exceptions that are out of the scope of this answer) so even though `JwtAuthModule` does export the `JwtAuthGuard` it doesn't actually mean that Nest will use that exported provider to make the instance from `@UseGuards()` in the `UserModule`'s `UserController`.

Hopefully that all makes sense

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this for me! You were right, as you were writing your answer, I added a little bit of context to my question, I indeed use `UseGuards` in my `UsersController`. If by *enhancers* you refer to decorators (I didn't know it was also called enhancers), then yes it all makes sense!

Comment: By enhancers I mean Guards, Pipes, Interceptors, and Filters. They're like pseudo providers that have certain functionalities and places in the framework, rather than general providers than can be used freely

Comment: Got it! Thanks again for your time!